# leetcode 092 reverse between - why my submission #2 is slower than #1?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here are my 2 submissions of [Reverse Linked List II](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list-ii/):

```
// #1
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right)
        return head;

    // always the precedence node next pointer addr
    // when left == 1, it goes to the head variable addr
    ListNode** left_pred_next_addr = &head;
    for (int i = 1; i < left; ++i)
        left_pred_next_addr = &(*left_pred_next_addr)->next;

    ListNode* p = *left_pred_next_addr;
    ListNode* q = p->next;
    ListNode* t;

    ListNode* right_node_next = p;
    for (int i = left; i <= right; ++i)
        right_node_next = right_node_next->next;

    for (;;)
    {
        t = q->next;
        q->next = p;
        if (t == right_node_next)
            break;
        p = q;
        q = t;
    }
    (*left_pred_next_addr)->next = right_node_next;
    *left_pred_next_addr = q;
    return head;
}
```

```
Status      Runtime Memory  Language
Accepted    0 ms    7.5 MB  cpp
```

```
// #2
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right)
        return head;

    ListNode** left_pred_next_addr = &head;
    for (int i = 1; i < left; ++i)
        left_pred_next_addr = &(*left_pred_next_addr)->next;

    ListNode* p = *left_pred_next_addr;
    ListNode* q = p->next;
    ListNode* t = nullptr;

    ListNode* right_node_next = p;
    for (int i = left; i < right; ++i)
    {
        t = q->next;
        q->next = p;
        p = q;
        q = t;
    }
    (*left_pred_next_addr)->next = t;
    // (*left_pred_next_addr)->next = right_node_next;
    *left_pred_next_addr = p;
    return head;
}
```

```
Status      Runtime Memory  Language
Accepted    4 ms    7.5 MB  cpp
```

The 2nd saves a `[left, right]` run, then it should run faster my 1st submission.

But leetcode returns slower results.

Tested both methods twice, got the same output.

Does leetcode run tests with debug code (assumes no optimization) or not?

Comment: *Does leetcode run tests with debug code (assumes no optimization) or not?* -- Run the tests yourself on your own compiler, using your own optimization settings, using your own data.  Why are you relying on any statistics "leetcode" is giving you?   If you want to benchmark your code online, go to a site that actually performs benchmarks, such as [this one](https://quick-bench.com/).

Comment: Had run local debug builds with VS2019, my improvement is perfect.

Comment: Don't run debug builds -- run optimized, release builds.  Timing a debug build is pointless.